# Remove text regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I wrote a **scraper** in python

```
source =  requests.get(url)
soup =  BeautifulSoup(source.text,features="lxml")
var = soup.find("span", class_="result")
print(var)
```

This is result

```
 <span class="result">Betheme</span>
```

Now I need to print result without span class. Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to tell without the data you're parsing, but I'd imagine `var.contents` has what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean just the text "Betheme" than add

```
print(var.text)
```